# How to delete all favorites using python? Can't delete, getting errors. Need solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I've tried to make a python script that can delete / undo favorite all my twitter favorites for me. I have seen [MATHEW INKSON's post](http://www.mathewinkson.com/2015/03/delete-old-tweets-selectively-using-python-and-tweepy) to do the job. I don't need to delete my tweets, just want to clear the favorites. Besides that script is almost two years old and incompatible with latest python. So I've edited a little to run it with python 3.6.0 and my script look like this:

```
    import tweepy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

test_mode = False
verbose = False
delete_favs = True
days_to_keep = 7

consumer_key = 'my consumer key'
consumer_secret = 'my consumer secret'
access_token = 'my access token'
access_token_secret = 'my access token secret'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

cutoff_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=days_to_keep)

if delete_favs:
    print ("Retrieving favorited tweets")
    favorites = tweepy.Cursor(api.favorites).items()
    unfav_count = 0
    kept_count = 0

    for tweet in favorites:
        if tweet.created_at < cutoff_date:
            if verbose:
                print ("Unfavoring %d: [%s] %s % (tweet.created_at,tweet.text)")
                if not test_mode:
                    api.destroy_favorite(tweet.id)
                    unfav_count += 1
                else:
                    kept_count += 1
                print ("Unfavored %d tweets, ignored %d" % (unfav_count, kept_count))
```

But, everytime by running the script on my windows command I am getting this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\New folder\Unfavorite.py", line 25, in <module>

for tweet in favorites:
File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 49, in __next__

File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 197, in next

File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 108, in next

File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call

File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute

tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 429
```

I am using Python 3.6, my app's permissions are all correct. Everything is fine with my twitter app. I guess something is wrong with my script. 
Please someone help fix my code. I've seen some other script too. Those didn't work out. Suggestions will be appreciated. 
 Thanks is advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because spam.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Comment: @AlisterBulman just vandalizing post, if spam, then flag at it as such don't vote to close, any way this is not spam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Twitter response codes](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes), Code 429 is Returned in when a request cannot be served due to the application’s rate limit having been exhausted for the resource. Which means your app has made too many requests and you have to look into [API Rate limits.](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting)

Comment: I usually use time.sleep() when my api makes too many requests to put some time gap between 2 requests ... you can also try putting sleep in for loop. Else you can try getting new api session after certain limit.

Comment: In docs, they have mentioned that "Rate limiting of the API is primarily on a per-user basis — or more accurately described, per user access token. If a method allows for 15 requests per rate limit window, then it allows 15 requests per window per access token."

Comment: Please upvote the answer if addresses your question,

Comment: try it after  api.destroy_favorite(tweet.id)

Comment: @SMMahmudulHasan The rate limit duration is 15 minutes. You will probably have to wait until the current limit has expired before trying again.